# Camel - Property parameter passing to a method is not working in choice/when

Tags: apache-camel

I'm working with Camel (v2.17.3) using Spring (v4.3.2.RELEASE) and have trouble with passing property parameter to a method.

I've tried to do a choice/when, but it passed the plain string not the value of the property {{elmu.inMask}}):

```
    <choice>
        <when>
            <method ref="eleoHelper" method="checkInMask(${exchange}, ${file:name}, {{elmu.inMask}})" />
            <log message="${body}" />
        </when>
    </choice>
```

Finally, I figured out when I use the same in setHeader (and the header's value as a workaround in choice/when), it's working well.

```
    <setHeader headerName="toCollect">
        <method ref="eleoHelper" method="checkInMask(${exchange}, ${file:name}, {{elmu.inMask}})" />
    </setHeader>
```

But I've several properties, and I don't like this workaround.

The property bean definition:

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="location" value="file:ELEOSFTP.properties" />
    <property name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

Cold you tell me what is wrong in my code and how can I use property values in choice/when?

Answer (score 0):

Those are bean properties. I would guess you need to create setters/getters and a class variable in order to map the property.

Standard properties defined in `<cm:properties>` can be referred in the way you have done.

Comment: Thanks. My project is a simple spring xml, not OSGI. I've never used the <cm:properties> tag, neither your other suggestion.

Comment: I'm a newbie in Camel. I can do workaround(but don't want), I really do not understand why not working the substitution in when while the same working in setHeader?

Comment: Ok in that case you need to bridge Camel and Spring. See here: http://camel.apache.org/properties.html in the section on bridging camel and spring. See also more info here: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html

Comment: Thanks. I read that section, but cannot find how to set the encoding of the bridge. But I gave it a try: the result is the same. The method call in when fails:     <method ref="eleoHelper" method="checkInMask($simple{exchange}, $simple{file:name}, {{elmu.inMask}})" />

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
method=checkInMask($exchangeProperty.<property name>)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my properties in a file not in the Exchange.